# Flex Icon on Button sizing [Design]

Tags: apache-flex, button, coding-style

I would like to size the width of my button according to its icon image.
I tried to force padding to 0 with no success.

In a tile

```
<mx:Button id="m1"  icon="@Embed('m1.png')"/>
```

See the result

http://img513.imageshack.us/my.php?image=iconkg3.png

How could i change this gap ?

[icon http://img513.imageshack.us/my.php?image=iconkg3.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/my.php?image=iconkg3.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add a listener on creationComplete event and you can use this code:

```
    private function OnCreationComplete(event: Event): void
    {
        if (event.target is Button)
        {
            var button: Button = (event.target as Button);
            var icon: DisplayObject = button.getChildByName("upIcon");
            if (icon) // check icon existence
            {
                button.width = icon.width;
                button.height = icon.height;
            }
        }
    }
```

Should work...